# AppScript Slides Get Hex Code of Text Box

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-slides

For Apps Script, I'm trying to print the Hex code of the fill of text box.
Any ideas. I'm stuck once I get to `.getSolidFill()`.
This line does not work for me: `shape.getFill().getSolidFill().getColor().asRgbColor().asHexString())`

```
function adjustFillColor() {


  // // Open the presentation and get the slides in it.
  let deck = SlidesApp.openById(masterDeckID);
  let slides = deck.getSlides();

  let masterSlide = slides[1];

  let slide = masterSlide.duplicate();

  slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => { // Iterate through every shape in the slide
          if (shape.getFill().getSolidFill()!== null){
              shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#000000");
          }
      
    });               
   
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
console.log("Color String: " +shape.getFill().getSolidFill());
```

#### To:

```
console.log("Color String: " + shape.getFill().getSolidFill().getColor().asRgbColor().asHexString());
```

- When this modified script is run, you can retrieve the color of shapes as the HEX value.
- Or, how about the following modification?

  - From

    ```
      slide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
         if (shape.getFill().getSolidFill()!== null)
            console.log("Color String: " +shape.getFill().getSolidFill());
    ```
  - To

    ```
      masterSlide.getShapes().forEach(shape => {
        var solidFill = shape.getFill().getSolidFill();
        var color = solidFill && solidFill.getColor();
        var rgbColor = color && color.getColorType() == SlidesApp.ColorType.RGB ? color.asRgbColor() : null;
        if (solidFill && color && rgbColor) {
          console.log("Color String: " + rgbColor.asHexString());
        }
      });
    ```

#### References:

- [getSolidFill()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/fill#getSolidFill())
- [getColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/solid-fill#getColor())
- [asRgbColor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/color#asRgbColor())
- [asHexString()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/rgb-color.html#asHexString())

Comment: thanks for the help, but that throws an error for me. it states Exception: Object is not of type RgbColor.

Comment: What's the best way to share the slide?

Comment: @gus Thank you for replying. In your script, the error proceess is not included. So, I reflected the error process in your script. Could you please confirm my added modification?

Comment: @gus About `What's the best way to share the slide?`, I think that this is a new question. I would like to support you. But how about resolving from your 1st question in order?

Comment: @gus When I saw your updated script, `shape.getFill().setSolidFill("#000000");` is set the color. I had understood that you wanted to retrieve the color of the shape as the HEX value. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: your modification worked. Amazing. Thank you.

Comment: yes, i want to retrieve the color and then use that color to select the textbox.

Comment: @gus Thank you for replying and testing it. From `your modification worked. Amazing. Thank you.`, I understood that your 1st question was resolved. I'm glad for it.

Comment: @gus About your 2nd question of `What's the best way to share the slide?`, I think that it is required to know your actual situation. For example, if you want to manually share the Slides, you can do it by clicking "Share". If you want to share it using a script, you can do it using `deck.addEditors(["email1", "email2",,,])` in your script.

Comment: @gus Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.